# how to create a nested for loop that stores the hashed value for each

Tags: solidity, contract-design, mapping, arrays, sha3

I have two arrays:

```
address[ ] addresses
uint [ ] numbers
```

I want to create a function that creates another array that stores the hashed value of both.

```
bytes32[ ] addressNumbers
```

for instance, if I have two addresses stored and two uints:

```
address[address1, address2] addresses,
uint [1, 2] numbers.
```

I want to hash them with `keccak256(address, uint)` such that i get an array:

```
bytes 32[ address1,1 ,address1,2 , address2,1 , address2,2 ] 
addressNumbers
```

I assume I need to use a nested for loop, but i am having trouble figuring out how. can any of you help me put?

Comment: Needs adaptation to the way Ethereum works. What are you going to do with the hashes?

Comment: it is in relation to another question on here:
http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13994/access-one-structs-member-from-another-struct-inside-the-same-contract#new-answer

i want to join the two arrays to create voterIssues for each voter on each issue.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is treat it as a many-to-many join between two tables, Voters and Issues. The relationship is usually addressed with a third table, in this case Vote (or Ballet if it reduces confusion).

In summary, push Voters and Issues into tables (arrays, or mappings with indexes). Some patterns here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Pick a pattern that lets you easily confirm a Voter is actually registered and an Issue actually exists. Then hash the keys and push a Vote into the Vote table.

By "table" I mean one of the constructs described in the above-linked answer. Think about the strengths a weaknesses and choose accordingly. For the votes themselves, I would consider:

```
struct Vote {
  bool yayNay;
  bool isVote;
}

mapping(she3HashKey => Vote) voteStructs;
```

The second field would be set to true for all votes cast so you can tell a real "false" from a default 0, because ...

*In my approach*, you need simple functions to check if things exist:

```
isVoter() public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {}
isIssue() public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {}
isVote()  public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {}
```

That's a must or you might get tangled up in awkward problems, e.g. differentiating a default (false) from an actual "Nay".

Check the first two before you allow a new Vote.

```
if(!isVoter(msg.sender)) throw;
if(!isIssue(issueId)) throw;
// continue ...
```

Check the third one before you do anything with a stored Vote.

Keep your tallies as you go so you can avoid iteration at all costs.

Hope it helps.